Fuse temperature
Morning could some give advise on the next matter:
What will be the fuse temp. by changing the Voltage from 27 volt to 24 Volt at the same resistance.
All voltage supplied through Meanwell power supply (potted type)
Regards Wim

The fuse temperature is dependent on the current going through the fuse, not the voltage across it. So the question you should be asking yourself is: "How much will the current change if I increase the voltage?", and for that question I would point to Ohms law (V = R * I).

Clear answer however what will be the relation to the temperature.

Your english is very hard to understand, could you try to rephrase your question more carefully & properly, so that I don't misunderstand what you are asking?

Please revisit How do I ask a Good Question. Use the Your Answer post editor for answering the question, only

Both 24 V or 27 V across any normal fuse will blow it almost instantly. The assumption I make therefore is that the fuse is being used in a circuit that has a power supply of either 24 V or 27 V. The power supply voltage has no effect on the temperature of the fuse, or the current at which it blows.
